# Jquery/ Javascript code to test drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, automation

I'm wondering is there a way to perform a drag and drop web testing using jquery/javascript. In the following code I have a list of items that are draggable      .

```
    <div id="available" class="TEST" style="height:300px;width:250px;font-size:1.2em;border:2px solid #ccc; padding:1em;overflow:auto; " data-dojo-type="dojo.dnd.Source">
    <div id="18" class="dojoDndItem" style="padding:.5em;">1</div>
    <div id="130" class="dojoDndItem" style="padding:.5em;">2</div>
```

This is the location I wish to drop each item I select. I have tried using selenium but I cannot select the item by tag or any time I have it has failed using a robot worked for me but the pixel location makes automation difficult. If there was a way to remove an item from list one and added it to list 2 that would also work for me .

```
 <div id="drop" class="test" style="height:300px;width:250px;font-size:1.2em;border:2px solid #ccc; p </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean you have a working application and you're trying to write automated tests for it, right? What server-side language is your app written in? For Ruby/Rails stacks, [Capybara has decent support for simulating drag-and-drop](http://heywill.com/blog/2012/12/15/using-capybara-to-drag-a-jquery-ui-sortable-onto-a-jquery-ui-droppable) as long as you're using a driver that also supports it (like [Poltergeist / PhantomJS](https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist#whats-supported)).

EDIT: Sorry, if I understand you properly you're trying to do integration tests within Javascript, right? If so I'm guessing you'll need a testing environment that uses a headless browser like PhantomJS, which literally executes all JS on the page (or [is supposed to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28389135/rails-page-js-works-in-real-browser-manual-testing-but-not-in-phantomjs-sele)) and internally represents the page spatially in a similar way to how real browsers do.

It looks like http://docs.busterjs.org/en/latest/ and http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/testing-javascript-with-phantomjs--net-28243 are a couple places to start figuring out what's the best way to approach automated JS integration tests.

Comment: Yes that's correct.It is all written in java, selenium cannot automate this drag and drop. So I'm hoping to find an answer with jquery/javascript.

Comment: You mean Java not JS? Looks like there's a native Java driver for PhantomJS, I'm not familiar enough with the Java community to evaluate it though: https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver Good luck!